# Do Passives stack when added by Hellfire Amulet?

Tags: diablo-iii

The Hellfire Amulet introduced in patch 2.1 has a secondary affix that adds the effect a random passive ability for your class. If you do this on Monk and get Fleet Footed (Increase movement speed by 10%), will this increase movement speed if worn by a Monk who already uses Fleet Footed?

Comment: I don't think the passives stack.  Some of them would be extremely powerful at twice the values.  And your regular passive slots don't allow you to choose the same one more than once.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The devs had a [chat](http://youtu.be/gff8Sh7YiIU?t=51m30s) a few days ago, and one of the things they discussed was Hellfire Amulets.  From the transcript:

> The Hellfire Amulet is a regular amulet with the standard 4/2 affixes, but one of the secondary affixes rolls one of your class’ passive skills. Enabling that passive for free. They don’t stack, so you can’t have say… Archery twice. But if you can get Archery on the amulet, then your Demon Hunter is free to pick another skill for your fourth passive. It’s a lot of power and it’s a way for players to find something else to do.

This is roughly at the 50 minute mark, and discusses the Amulet specifically.

Answer (score 4):

I have tested this several time on the PTR and no it doesn't, passives effect don't stack with the Hellfire Amulet.